# array content changes for every loop variable stays the same

Tags: arrays, vb.net, variables, loops

in the array arr1 is the first row of a csv table, in which are addresses are stored.
it is read in by streamdreader.readline  and then splittet and saved in array arr1.

A Form1 shows a datagridview with two columns first columns with the fields of the Array. second column has comboboxes with possibly columns in the sql database in which the scv shall be saved.
after the user maps the two columns by using the combo box. 
comes the snippet code:

'the loop shall check for each row, which comboboxelement is selected by comparing the strings.

```
Dim feld(arr1.Length)
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To arr1.Length - 1 Step +1
    feld(i) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
    If feld(i) = "Postleitzahl" Then
        Postleitzahlvar = arr1(i)
    ElseIf feld(i) = "Nachname" Then
        Nachnamevar = arr1(i)
    ElseIf feld(i) = "Vorname" Then
        Vornamevar = arr1(i)
    End If
Next
```

After that there is another loop which:
1. reads line of cvs file
2. puts the line slpitted in arr1
3. uses the variables from the first loop(postleitzahlvar, nachnamevar, vornamevavr) and puts them as parameters in the insert command for the sql database.

until last line

The problem is that the variables
postleitzahlvar
nachnamevar
vornamevar

do not change their value. while the value of the array fields change.

this means i get every insert i do in the loop a datarow which contains the attributes from the csv´s first row

I hope you can help out guys. I know it is much to read. but i struggled many hours today to solve my problem. i dont know why it doesnt work with I (index) variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of saving the values from your first row, you probably want to get the column indexes instead.  They will help you put the right columns (from the CSV) into the database columns.

Try this:

```
Dim feld(arr1.Length)
Dim Ppostleitzahlindex as integer, Nachnameindex as integer, Vornameindex as integer
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To arr1.Length - 1 Step +1

    feld(i) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString

    If feld(i) = "Postleitzahl" Then
        Postleitzahlvar = arr1(i) 'probably not what you want
        Postleitzahlindex = i     'array index is more useful
    ElseIf feld(i) = "Nachname" Then
        Nachnamevar = arr1(i)
        Nachnameindex = i
    ElseIf feld(i) = "Vorname" Then
        Vornamevar = arr1(i)
        Vornameindex = i
    End If
Next
```

...and then when you read each row,  split the columns and load your insert parameters from the columns by index.  Here is the pseudo-code:

```
'for each line in the csv file
  'Read line
  'split line into arr1

  'parameter Postleitzahl = arr1(Postleitzahlindex)
  'parameter Nachname = arr1(Nachnameindex)
  'parameter Vorname = arr1(Vornameindex)

  'insert
'until end of file
```

Comment: thx for the answer, I will check this out as soon as I enter the Company